# Cache only the latest version of javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, svn, caching, browser-cache

I am having trouble with javascript files being cached by the browser, even though I use

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

in htaccess to check the modified time and size to see if it is the latest version. I currently include javascript files like so:

```
<script src="/code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried to add SVN revision information to the file call like so:

```
<script src="/code.js?svn=123" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but I could not find a bullet-proof approach to do it, since I could not get a revision by file name (any suggestions) and even though I add the revision, the HTML is being precompiled and cached by Smarty.

So I thought about using no cache blocks for the template, but I haven't tried this approach yet. Will there be any difference since the files are compiled only once?

So basically I'm just collecting ideas on how to force the browser to only cache the latest version of the file. The ideal solution would be through htaccess that actually works, not like FileETag, since with that, you always have to press CTRL+F5 to get the latest version anyway.

Answer (score 2):

adding a cache buster either into the file path is the best way to go. you can do it through the `?` approach like you have here, or add it into a path to the file like: `/static/123/code.js`

after that you add an expires header 10 years into the future, and you are good to go. So the question you have is how to generate the number in the url. Maybe you can change your deploy script to replace bump that number up when you do the deployment, that way you dont need to care about version numbers

another thought would be to compute an md5 hash of the js file and use that in the path.

Comment: I didn't think of hashing the file contents for the unique identifier, good thought!

Comment: Although the ? approach forces some browsers (at least Firefox) to always send a request to the server, regardless of the expiration date. Usually a short NOT MODIFIED response comes back, but still. Also, using the last modified date as cache buster suffices and is way easier to get than an MD5.

Comment: Good thought as well on the modified date ID, but I deploy quite often, and the deployment changes all of the files, so subversion number adding or content hashing is still the way to go for me, since otherwise I would ruin every users' cache every time I deploy. The question is now, how do I add the hash to the request through htaccess or other means and not through code? Is that at all possible?

Comment: I ended up using modified time hash, since it was the fastest ID generation method. Using svn revision or file contents for hashing took about 2 seconds. Since I'm calculating the hashes on the fly and not when deploying, that would take way too long. @WolfgangStengel, if you would write your comment as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Good to hear. No worries on the answer, you can accept the one from mkoryak, the information is all here.